# What is this screen and how do I get rid of it?

Tags: lock-screens, google-pixel

Today my pixel 2 randomly decided to show this screen after I log in.

[image: screen that shows up after I unlock with my finger pad]

Where did it come from and how do I eliminate the extra step before being able to access my phone?

Comment: It might be from touch pal keyboard.You can now turn this latest intrusive Touchpal off via 'settings' > 'look and feel' > 'lucky locker. Or look in touch pla keyboard settings

Comment: Do you refer to the lower part of the screen, the upper part, or all of it? Installed anything lately – especially any app related to "battery optimization"? Taking a closer look at the upper-right corner: @Abochur seems to have hit the nail. A search for "Lucky Locker" turns up tons of cry on "Stop Lucky Locker, TouchPal!"

Comment: I guess it's UC Browser..

Comment: Many Android applications have junk adware like this. Check what apps you installed recently, one of them may be the culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the sort of thing you get from an app that comes with ads. Check what apps you've recently installed and force close the offending app to remove the screen.

Comment: What does that have to do with VPN? It's an ad that could come from your favorite torch app or your latest game as well.

Comment: Just an example of an app you might install - I used that example since I've had a similar thing from a VPN app.

Comment: Maybe just make that "an app that comes with ads"? Otherwise it always looks as if VPN apps would be especially affected by this, which definitely is not the case. Black sheep are everywhere. And in the OP's case, I'd say that black sheep is identified, and not a VPN ;)